What is the significance of Genesis 1:28 in the context of God's creation decree, and how does the Fall relate to the creation decree?
Genesis 1:28 reveals a critical component of God's creation decree, encapsulating humanity's purpose and role within creation. By blessing humanity and commanding them to be fruitful, multiply, fill the earth, and subdue it, God’s will is reflected. This verse emphasizes humanity's unique position as image-bearers of God and as agents entrusted with responsibility and authority over the earth.
The Fall, as seen in the context of Genesis 2:15-17 and 3:13, followed by the resulting curses, presents an apparent dramatic divergence from God's creation decree as expressed in Genesis 1:28. It alters the timeline of God's creation decree, disrupting the harmony and order of creation and fracturing relationships—between humanity and God, among human beings, and with creation itself.
Text:(NET)

Genesis 1:28 - God blessed them and said to them, “Be fruitful and
multiply! Fill the earth and subdue it! Rule over the fish of the sea
and the birds of the air and every creature that moves on the ground.”


Genesis 2: 15-17 - The Lord God took the man and placed him in the
orchard in Eden to care for it and to maintain it. 16Then the Lord God
commanded the man, “You may freely eat fruit from every tree of the
orchard, 17but you must not eat from the tree of the knowledge of good
and evil, for when you eat from it you will surely die.


Genesis 3:13 - So the Lord God said to the woman, “What is this you have done?” And
the woman replied, “The serpent tricked me, and I ate.”


This appears to be a statement rather than a question (with which I agree).

Thank you for your comment and agreement. This post aims to draw out some contextual and exegetical insights on the significance of Genesis 1:28 as part of God's creation decree and how the Fall relates to, interacts with, and impacts this decree. I’d love to hear your thoughts on how the creation decree and the Fall interact and impact theological understanding..

I and other have written books on this subject - it is very large.  Further, there are numerous facets to the significance of this incident and its consequences.

Thank you for your thoughtful comment! It sounds like your work could provide valuable insights into the topic. While I understand the subject is vast and multifaceted, I’d love to hear a concise summary or key points from your perspective. A shorter version would help the community engage more effectively and benefit from the depth of your expertise. Looking forward to your insights!

1. The Significance of Genesis 1:28 in God's Creation Decree
Genesis 1:28 reveals humanity’s pivotal role as God’s image-bearers, entrusted with His blessings, authority, and mandates to steward creation and to participate in the realization of 'Thy Kingdom come, on earth as it is in heaven.' This verse not only highlights humanity’s privileged position but also their responsibility to align their free will with God’s eternal purpose.
Free-Will Agents in God’s Plan
God’s creation timeline hinges on the critical role of human obedience. While God’s will is sovereign and unchanging, Genesis 1:28 reveals that humanity’s free will plays an active role in the fulfillment of His purposes.
Humanity, created in God’s image, was endowed with the capacity to choose obedience and align with God’s divine order, or to rebel and disrupt the harmony of creation. This 'dual potentiality' underscores both the trust and the responsibility bestowed upon humanity as free-will agents. However, Scripture makes it clear that human free will operates within the boundaries of God’s sovereignty, never entirely autonomous but always subject to His overarching domain.
Even after the Fall, humanity’s role as free-will agents remains central to God’s purposes. Through faith and obedience, believers are called to participate in the work of redemption, proclaiming the gospel of Jesus Christ to all nations and bearing witness to God’s kingdom and glory.
The Creation Mandate
God’s command to “be fruitful, multiply, and have dominion” underscores His intent for humanity to thrive under His care and blessing reflecting His glory in their stewardship. Yet, the same free will that empowers them to fulfill this mandate also carries the potential to disrupt it.
The Sacred Trust Broken
As both agents and beneficiaries, humanity holds the unique ability to shape creation’s timeline within God’s sovereign plan. However, the Creation Timeline, as outlined in Genesis 1:28, was disrupted when humanity, by their own volition, turned against God’s will.
The God who decreed the Creation Timeline, filled with blessings and goodwill for humanity and the world—repeatedly declaring, "It was good" and "It was very good"—and who instituted the Sabbath as a gift to humanity, did not preordain Adam and Eve to fall.
This rebellion not only broke the sacred trust between humanity and God but also necessitated the decree of the Redemption Plan—a timeline that intersects with the disrupted Creation Timeline and works to restore it to its original intent.
God’s Eternal Will and Human Free Will
Genesis 1:28, alongside the prohibition in Genesis 2:17, underscores that humanity’s adherence to God’s laws and commandments, as pre-established by Him, is essential for fulfilling His will. In His sovereignty, God willed and foreordained human participation by granting the autonomy of free will, deeming it integral to the realization of the Creation Timeline. Throughout Scripture, God’s valuation of human free will is evident (e.g., John 3:16), even as He fully understands that it carries the potential for deviations from His intended purposes.
In His omnipotence and omniscience, God sovereignly chose to grant this freedom, fully aware of its potential outcomes and willing to bear the cost of redemption. This principle is reflected repeatedly, as when God led Israel, His chosen people, into the promised land despite knowing their future rebellions (Deuteronomy 32:15-16, 20-21). Such examples reveal the profound mystery of God’s grace and unwavering commitment to His eternal will, even amid human failure.
This highlights a significant doctrinal implication: humanity’s unique role as free-will agents means that, while God’s eternal will remain unchanging, its realization intersects with human choices. This interplay does not diminish God’s sovereignty but magnifies the One who declares, “I AM who I AM” (אֶֽהְיֶ֑ה אֲשֶׁ֣ר אֶֽהְיֶ֖ה), the omnipotent and omniscient One, who decreed the Redemptive Plan in eternity, even for those who would rebel and choose to be enemies of God.
Still, why did God create human beings as He did? The answer may lie latent in the creation order and the unique manner of humanity’s formation: being made in His image, formed from the dust of the earth, and given life by the breath of God. This sacred act set humanity apart as living beings, entrusted with blessings and the divine mandate to flourish, steward creation, and reflect His glory.
No other creation, creature, or humanoid robot, for that matter, can serve as God’s counterpart agent except humanity—a living being (חַיָּֽה׃ לְנֶ֥פֶשׁ), uniquely designed to embody His image and participate in His eternal purposes, bringing Him pleasure and glory.
2. How does the Fall relate to the creation decree?
The Fall, recorded in Genesis 3, represents a dramatic disruption of the Creation Decree outlined in Genesis 1 and 2. While humanity’s role as God’s image-bearers, their stewardship over creation, and the mandate to multiply and fill the earth remain intact, sin fractures creation’s harmony and delays the realization of God’s purposes. These purposes ultimately culminate in the Kingdom of God—a theme central to Jesus’ teachings and the visions in Revelation. Without this ultimate goal, the Creation Timeline loses its full theological coherence.
Unlike the Creation Timeline, which reflects God’s perfect and unbroken will, the Christ-centric Redemptive-Historical Timeline unfolds through time, locality, and people, redeeming fallen humanity through the gospel and restoring creation. This timeline, established in response to the Fall, fulfills God’s original decree and culminates in the Kingdom of God, where His creation purposes are fully realized as revealed in the Book of Revelation.
Conclusion:
Genesis 1:28 is a cornerstone of the biblical creation narrative, revealing humanity’s unique role as God’s image-bearers. It emphasizes the blessings, authority, and responsibility entrusted to humanity to steward creation and align their will with God’s eternal purposes.
The Fall disrupted this original timeline, introducing sin and separation, but it did not nullify God’s ultimate plan. Through the Plan of Redemption, history was redirected toward the fulfillment of the Kingdom of God, where His presence, justice, and peace will fully reign.
The interplay between God’s sovereignty and human free will is essential to understanding the Creation Decree. While God’s will is sovereign, its fulfillment engages human choices and obedience, underscoring the profound role of free-will agents in His plan.
Despite humanity’s betrayal, God’s unwavering grace ensures that His purposes prevail. The Creation Timeline, though disrupted, finds its ultimate culmination in the New Heaven and New Earth, where His kingdom is fully restored, and His glory fills all creation.
To neglect either God’s sovereignty or human free will in theological discussions risks distorting Scripture and dishonoring God.Only by embracing both elements—God’s sovereignty and human free will—can we fully grasp the balanced message of Scripture and faithfully represent the God who “so loved the world that He gave His only Son” to bring salvation to all (John 3:16).

The significance  of Gen. 1:28 can hardly be overstated. It is the means by which God's purpose of creation is to be fulfilled. The OP is quite correct when it says of the Fall:

It alters the timeline of God's creation decree, disrupting the
harmony and order of creation and fracturing relationships—between
humanity and God, among human beings, and with creation itself.

However, although God's timeline may have been interrupted, his ultimate purpose is not frustrated. As Isaiah 55:11 says:

So shall my word be that goes forth from my mouth; It shall not return
to me empty, but shall do what pleases me, achieving the end for which
I sent it.

God worked with humankind to establish his chosen people. He renewed a blessing similar to that Gen. 1:28 several times: to Noah, Abraham and finally Jacob. It would be Jacob's descendants, the Israelites, who finally established the national foundation on which, for Christians, a new Adam would come, namely Jesus (1 Corinthians 15:45). The New Testament teaches that Christ will return, but there are varying conceptions as to whether the Second Advent involves a restoration of the blessing of Gen. 1:28.
For Jews too there is a messianic hope for the realization of Adam kadmon in which the ideal of God and humankind alike will be restored. However, it should be noted that the Jewish interpretation of the first sin does not involve a degradation of human nature, and so does not disrupt the relation between God and human beings as radically as in the Christian idea.
Summary: For Christians who reject the doctrine of strict predestination, the Fall indeed interrupts God's timeline for the realization of the blessings given in Gen. 1:28. Indeed the Bible may be seen as a record of God's work throughout history to help humankind get back on track.
